# How to recognize a large object like Building in vuforia

Tags: android, object, vuforia

I wanted to develop an android application for recognize some infrastructure (like building , statue , or  some large object ).

But the vuforia object scanner support only for tiny / small object by object scanning target image.

by this method scanning a building or large object is impossible.

how can i make the database of that kind of  object.

can anyone help me to this issue...?

NB: i am developing my app in android studio.

Comment: You can try with photo of building and then recognize it as a Image Target. The performance will be poor for sure, but there is no option to recognize and track objects this big as buildings.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking will be problematic for any AR SDK, not only Vuforia, since there is indeed a difficulty here - scanning a very large object is physically problematic, and will also result in a huge amount of features or detection parameters.

I would suggest considering identifying a part of the building as a regular 2D target - there must be a part of the building that will have enough features to be detected, and at a reasonable distance from where a potential user will be standing with the device.